# Function within exported array in Firefox Add-on SDK not available

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a module, which exports an array holding objects including function parameters:

```
var myArray = [
  {
    id: "firstObject",
    func: function() {
      console.log("Hi from function!");
    }
  }
];

exports myArray = myArray;
```

This module is included in another script, which emits an event to a client side script and passes the array as parameter:

```
var {myArray} = require("./array.js");

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  self.port.emit("someEvent", myArray[i]);
}
```

On the client side I can now access the `id` of the object but not the function held by the `func` parameter. Actually, the `func` parameter is not set at all on the client side.

Why is that? And how to circumvent that?

Comment: There is a syntax error at myArray, can you correct it and try again?

Comment: Thanks! I've corrected it. The code I've posted is only example code, the real code I am working on is at [GitHub](https://github.com/Elchi3/mdn-doc-tests/blob/master/data/doctests.js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs about port.emit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port#port.emit%28%29) say:

> The payload can be any value that is serializable to JSON.

and [functions are not JSON serializable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port#JSON-Serializable_Values), and as such they won't be encoded when you emit the message.

In order to circumvent that issue, you must move that logic from your object to addon's main script or to the content script: it depends on what you need to do with that message.

Comment: Thank you! That's it. I've found that answer in the meantime, though you were faster to post it. :-)